# difference between the phrases " make up to someone" and " make it up to someone "

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

Is there any difference between the meaning of *make up to someone* and *make it up to someone*?

Answer (score 1):

"Make up to someone" isn't used in the UK. If you have had an argument with someone and there is bad feeling between the two of you, you might decide to "Make it up with them".

On the other hand, if you have done something to cause them some form of loss, then you might decide to "make it up to them" by putting wrong the right.

E.g.

> "My friend and I argued, but I have since made up with him."

Or,

> "I broke my friend's vase, but I have made it up to him by buying him a new one"

It's possible that the act of "making something up **to** someone" has the side-effect of "making it up **with** someone" if the person is angry with you for some loss you have caused them.

Comment: Also "make it up to someone" also implies you will provide some remedy for the loss. In the example you would have replaced or paid for the vase ("it") that you broke.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks - I should have made that clear, so have added it to my answer.